# Closure lost during callback defined in exec()

Tags: python, python-exec

It's my third day using Python, so forgive newbie mistakes. So here's my working code. *person.test()* registers a callback with the boss, the boss calls the callback, everything works fine.

```
class Boss:
  def registerCallback(self,cb):
    self.cb = cb
  def doCallback(self):
    self.cb()

class Person:
  def woot(self,data):
    print("Woot! ",data)

  def test(self,boss,data):
    def callback ():
      self.woot(data)
    boss.registerCallback(callback)    

boss = Boss()
person = Person()
person.test(boss,1)
boss.doCallback()
```

However, if I change move the callback into an exec(), the closure is lost. The callback runs, but *self* and *data* are unknown so the call to *self.woot(data)* fails.

```
class Boss:
  def registerCallback(self,cb):
    self.cb = cb
  def doCallback(self):
    self.cb()

class Person:
  def woot(self,data):
    print("Woot! ",data)

  def test(self,boss,data):
    x = "def callback():\n  self.woot(data)\nboss.registerCallback(callback)"
    exec(x,globals(),locals())

boss = Boss()
person = Person()
person.test(boss,1)
boss.doCallback()
```

I tried to compile() too, no luck. Any thoughts? I really don't want to manually carry a copy of self/data through the boss and back, because my real-life code is much more convoluted. I really need a way to maintain the closure.

Comment: My gut reaction is "Don't use `exec()`!" because it presents all kinds of issues that occur when you don't separate code and data. Why do you think you need exec() and for what? BTW, concerning callbacks, you know that instead of `foo.bar()` you can also write `tmp = foo.bar; tmp()`. This is often the easier way to create callbacks to an object. In your case, you pass along some data though, which is why it doesn't fully apply. There are libraries for function composition (binding parameters etc) included in Python that could be used instead.

Comment: I'm using exec() because the business logic is defined dynamically during runtime by the user while the application is running, the essential feature of this project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only pass `locals` (as the global data for the function), then things more or less work:

```
class Person:
  def woot(self,data):
    print("Woot! ",data)

  def test(self,boss,data):
    x = "def callback():\n  self.woot(data)\nboss.registerCallback(callback)"
    exec(x, locals())
```

of course, if you need the globals as well, you can pack them together:

```
def test(self, boss, data):
  namespace = globals().copy()
  local_copy = locals().copy()
  namespace.update(local_copy)
  x = 'def foo(): pass'
  exec(x, namespace)
```

Comment: Ah, looks like everything I need is stored in locals(), and thanks to Ashwini's answer below about why it's not being taken correctly... thanks to you both, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

**Why your current code fails?**

`self` is a free variable to `callback` and if you read [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#locals)'s documentation you will find:

> Free variables are returned by `locals()` when it is called in function
>   blocks, but not in **class blocks**.

And now from [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#exec)'s documentation:

> If `exec` gets two separate objects as globals and locals, the code will
>   be executed as if it were embedded in a **class definition**.

So, as we are passing two different objects to `exec()` the `locals()` dictionary is actually empty for `callback()` as it cannot access free variables anymore, hence the [solution suggested by @mgilson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28951120/846892) that passes merged version of `locals()` and `globals()` should do it for you.

Comment: @mgilson But in that case `self` is not a free variable to `foo` but a local variable.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake... I think we're probably saying the same thing here, just in different ways (and yours is probably the more "correct" way of saying it)

Comment: Either way, y'all both nailed it. Wish I could give you both credit.