# __closure__ attribute of function object always be 'None' when defining func inside exec()

Tags: python, closures, local-variables

### EDIT2：

A minimal demonstration is:

```
code = """\
a=1
def f1():
    print(a)
print(f1.__closure__)
f1()
"""

def foo():
    exec(code)

foo()
```

Which gives:

```
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/workfiles/test_eval_rec.py", line 221, in <module>
    foo()
  File "D:/workfiles//test_eval_rec.py", line 219, in foo
    exec(code)
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 3, in f1
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

It can be seen that the `__closure__` attribute of function defined inside code str passed to `exec()` is `None`, making calling the function fails.

Why does this happen and how can I define a function successfully?

---

I find several questions that may be related.

1. [Closure lost during callback defined in exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28950735/9758790)
2. [Using exec() with recursive functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/871887/9758790)
3. [Why exec() works differently when invoked inside of function and how to avoid it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55763182/9758790)
4. [Why are closures broken within exec?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2749655/9758790)
5. [NameError: name 'self' is not defined IN EXEC/EVAL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44603993/9758790)

These questions are all related to "defining a function insdie exec()". I think the fourth question here is closest to the essence of these problems. The common cause of these problems is that **when defining a function in exec(), the `__closure__` attribute of the function object can not be set correctly and will always be None.**  However, many existing answers to this question didn't realize this point.

**Why these questions are caused by wrong `__closure__`:**

When defining a function, `__closure__` attribute is set to a dict that contains all local symbols (at the place where the keyword `def` is used) that is used inside the newly defined funtion. When calling a function, local symbol tables will be retrived from the `__closure__` attribute. Since the `__closure__` is set to `None`, the local symbol tables can not be retrived as expected, making the function call fail.

**These answers work by making None a correct `__closure__` attribute:**

Existing solutions to the questions listed above solve these problems by getting the function definition rid of the usage of local symbol, i.e, they make the local symbols used(variable, function definition) global by passing globals() as locals of `exec` or by using keyword `global` explicitly in the code string.

**Why existing solution unsatisfying:**

These solutions I think is just an escape of the core problem of setting `__closure__` correctly when define a functioni inside `exec()`. And as symbols used in the function definition is made global, these solutions will produce redundant global symbol which I don't want.

---

### Original Questions：

***(You May ignore this session, I have figured something out, and what I currently want to ask is described as the session EDIT2. The original question can be viewed as a sepecial case of the question described in session EDIT2)***

original title of this question is: Wrapping class function to new function with exec() raise NameError that ‘self’ is not defined

I want to wrap an existing member function to a new class function. However, exec() function failed with a NameError that ‘self’ is not defined.

I did some experiment with the following codes. I called globals() and locals() in the execed string, it seems that the locals() is different in the function definition scope when exec() is executed. **"self" is in the locals() when in exec(), however, in the function definition scope inside the exec(), "self" is not in the locals().**

```
class test_wrapper_function():
    def __init__(self):
        # first wrapper
        def temp_func():
            print("locals() inside the function definition without exec:")
            print(locals())
            return self.func()

        print("locals() outside the function definition without exec:")
        print(locals())
        self.wrappered_func1 = temp_func

        # third wrapper using eval
        define_function_str = '''def temp_func():
    print("locals() inside the function definition:")
    print(locals())
    print("globals() inside the function definition:")
    print(globals())
    return self.func()
print("locals() outside the function definition:")
print(locals())
print("globals() outside the function definition:")
print(globals())
self.wrappered_func2 = temp_func'''
        exec(define_function_str)
        # call locals() here, it will contains temp_func

    def func(self):
        print("hi!")


t = test_wrapper_function()
print("**********************************************")
t.wrappered_func1()
t.wrappered_func2()
```

I have read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37152671/9758790). *In the exec()*, memeber function, attribute  of "self" can be accessed without problem, while *in the function difinition in the exec()*, "self" is not available any more. Why does this happen?

**Why I want to do this**:

I am building a PyQt program. I want to create several similar slots(). These slots can be generated by calling one member function with different arguments. I decided to generate these slots using exec() function of python. I also searched with the keyword "nested name scope in python exec", I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44603993/9758790) may be related, but there is no useful answer.

To be more specific. I want to define a family of slots like `func_X` (X can be 'a', 'b', 'c'...), each do something like `self.do_something_on(X)`. Here, `do_something` is a member function of my QWidget. So I use a for loop to create these slots function. I used codes like this:

```
class MyWidget():
    def __init__(self):
        self.create_slots_family()

    def do_something(self, character):
        # in fact, this function is much more complex. Do some simplification.
        print(character)

    def create_slots_i(self, character):
        # want to define a function like this:
        # if character is 'C', define self.func_C such that self.func_C() works like self.do_something(C)
        create_slot_command_str = "self.func_" + character + " = lambda:self.do_something('" + character + "')"
        print(create_slot_command_str)
        exec(create_slot_command_str)

    def create_slots_family(self):
        for c in ["A", "B", "C", "D"]:
            self.create_slots_i(c)

my_widget = MyWidget()
my_widget.func_A()
```

Note that, as far as I know, the Qt slots should not accept any parameter, so I have to wrap `self.do_something(character)` to be a series function `self.func_A`, `self.func_C` and so on for all the possible characters.

So the above is what I want to do orignially.

### EDIT1：

***(You May ignore this session, I have figured something out, and what I currently want to ask is described as the session EDIT2. This simplified version of original question can also be viewed as a sepecial case of the question described in session EDIT2)***

As @Mad Physicist suggested. I provide a simplified version here, deleting some codes used for experiments.

```
class test_wrapper_function():
    def __init__(self):
        define_function_str = '''\
def temp_func():
    return self.func()
self.wrappered_func2 = temp_func'''
        exec(define_function_str)

    def func(self):
        print("hi!")

t = test_wrapper_function()
t.wrappered_func2()
```

I expected this to print a "hi". However, I got the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/workfiles/test_eval_class4.py", line 12, in <module>
    t.wrappered_func2()
  File "<string>", line 2, in temp_func
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: Can I suggest that you stay as far away from exec as possible? You're much better off asking a question about how to solve your actual problem than trying to post this contrived monstrosity in hope that it ever works. XY problems aside, the question here should still be answerable

Comment: Please show your full output, and what you were expecting to get

Comment: Did you mean `def temp_func(self)` instead of just `def temp_func()`? This looks like a plain ol' typo.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for your help. I edit my question and delete some codes used for experiment. I want define a new class function `wrappered_func2(self)`, that works as `func(self)`. So I define a temp_func, I think the `self` is not needed. I need to define a member function to a function that taked no argument in.

Comment: If you want to place a function object in the class namespace and call it as a bound method, as you're trying to do, it needs a `self` argument. The bound nice method that is created by the descriptor that is your function will accept no arguments, but the function itself must accept an argument, which is why I'm voting to close as a typo

Comment: Thanks for your reply，it seems that my last comment is imprecise. I want to create  a new function object named ‘wrappered_func2’ and add it to the class as an attribute. And it is not a member function that needs a ‘self’ input. As you can see in the experimental codes, my codes work fine without using exec()

Comment: You're not adding it to a class, you're adding it to an instance, but `exec` is unable to make the closure correctly because you're not passing in `locals` from `__init__`. Close vote retracted

Comment: That being said, the solution in the link is adequate in your context

Comment: Also, the question that you say has no useful answer has a very useful, if highly downvoted, accepted answer

Comment: What happens if you do `exec(define_function_str, locals={'self': self})`?

Comment: I guess you mean `exec(define_function_str, globals(), {'self': self})`, I tried and got nothing different. I printed the 'locals()' in the executed str as mentioned in my question, and there is `self` in the locals()

Comment: Can you show the printouts? I'll play with this in the morning

Comment: If I use `exec(define_function_str, globals(), {'self': self})`, the TrackBack is exactly the same as I provided in the edited version of this question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2749655/2988730. It's py2, but the idea likely is the same

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28950735/2988730

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for your attention! I think my question is finally solved referring to the link you provided!

Comment: Glad it did. There's something very wrong with the solutions you are considering, so I'll post an answer in a bit. The real answer is to make the closure within `exec`, but at that point you really don't need `exec` at all: anything it can do will be done better (more safely and more elegantly) by the closure alone

Comment: @MadPhysicist Let me further explain why I want to use exec. I want define a lot of similar functions, like functions that is named like `function_a`, `function_b`, `function_c`...`function_z`,  All of functions in the function family is induced by calling a function `foo(arg)` with arguments `a`,`b`,`c`...`z`. I want to change use this family of function as slots of a family of Qt Signals `signal_a`, `signal_b`, `signal_c`...`signal_z`. I use `exec()` in for loop to avoid define these functions one by one. The Qt slots must be functions with no argument like these `function_X` .

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for your comments. However I couldn't recognize why my solution is wrong. And I can not find how to "make the closure within `exec`", I can not find a canonical way to "make the closure". I am looking forward to your answer eagerly!

Comment: I'm drafting something right now. Would you mind making an edit that shows a more representative string that has the name format?

Comment: @MadPhysicist What do you mean by "show a more representative string that has the name format"? I provide more details in the section "Why I want to do this", is this what you want me to do? Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: Yeah, that's perfect. I hadn't been keeping up with the edits. I'll try to post by this evening. Looks like you understand perfectly what's going on. There are just a couple of subtleties that you may not be aware of with globals.

Comment: Hopefully you move away from `exec` entirely after reading my answer. I think all you were looking for was `func.__name__`.

Answer (score 2):

**Using Exec**

You've already covered most of the problems and workarounds with `exec`, but I feel that there is still value in adding a summary.

The key issue is that `exec` only knows about `globals` and `locals`, but not about free variables and the non-local namespace. That is why the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) say

> If exec gets two separate objects as *globals* and *locals*, the code will be executed as if it were embedded in a class definition.

There is no way to make it run as though it were in a method body. However, as you've already noted, you can make `exec` create a closure and use that instead of the internal namespace by adding a method body to your snippet. However, there are still a couple of subtle restrictions there.

Your example of what you are trying to do showcases the issues perfectly, so I will use a modified version of that. The goal is to make a method that binds to `self` and has a variable argument in the `exec` string.

```
class Test:
    def create_slots_i(self, c):
        create_slot_command_str = f"self.func_{c} = lambda: self.do_something('{c}')"
        exec(create_slot_command_str)
    def do_something(self, c):
        print(f'I did {c}!')
```

There are different ways of getting `exec` to "see" variables: literals, globals, and internal closures.

1. **Literals**. This works robustly, but only for simple types that can be easily instantiated from a string. The usage of `c` above is a perfect example. This will not help you with a complex object like `self`:

   ```
   >>> t = Test()
   >>> t.create_slots_i('a')
   >>> t.func_a()
   ...
   NameError: name 'self' is not defined
   ```

   This happens exactly because `exec` has no concept of free variables. Since `self` is passed to it via the default `locals()`, it does not bind the reference to a closure.
2. **globals**. You can pass in a name `self` to `exec` via `globals`. There are a couple of ways of doing this, each with its own issues. Remember that `globals` are accessed by a function through its [`__globals__` (look at the table under "Callable types")](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) attribute. Normally `__globals__` refers to the `__dict__` of the module in which a function is defined. In `exec`, this is the case by default as well, since that's what `globals()` returns.

   - **Add to `globals`**: You can create a global variable named `self`, which will make your problem go away, sort of:

     ```
     >>> self = t
     >>> t.func_a()
     I did a!
     ```

     But of course this is a house of cards that falls apart as soon as you delete, `self`, modify it, or try to run this on multiple instances:

     ```
     >>> del self
     >>> t.func_a()
     ...
     NameError: name 'self' is not defined
     ```
   - **Copy `globals`**. A much more versatile solution, on the surface of it, is to copy `globals()` when you run `exec` in `create_slots_i`:

     ```
     def create_slots_i(self, c):
         create_slot_command_str = f"self.func_{c} = lambda: self.do_something('{c}')"
         g = globals().copy()
         g['self'] = self
         exec(create_slot_command_str, g)
     ```

     This appears to work normally, and for a very limited set of cases, it actually does:

     ```
     >>> t = Test()
     >>> t.create_slots_i('a')
     >>> t.func_a()
     I did a!
     ```

     But now, your function's `__globals__` attribute is no longer bound to the module you created it in. If it uses any other global values, especially ones that might change, you will not be able to see the changes. For limited functionality, this is OK, but in the general case, it can be a severe handicap.
3. **Internal Closures**. This is the solution you already hit upon, where you create a closure within the `exec` string to let it know that you have a free variable by artificial means. For example:

   ```
   class Test:
       def create_slots_i(self, c):
           create_slot_command_str = f"""def make_func(self):
       def func_{c}():
           self.do_something('{c}')
       return func_{c}
   self.func_{c} = make_func(self)"""
           g = globals().copy()
           g['self'] = self
           exec(create_slot_command_str, g)
       def do_something(self, c):
           print(f'I did {c}!')
   ```

   This approach works completely:

   ```
   >>> t = Test()
   >>> t.create_slots_i('a')
   >>> t.func_a()
   I did a!
   ```

   The only real drawbacks here are security, which is always a problem with `exec`, and the sheer awkwardness of this monstrosity.

**A Better Way**

Since you are already creating closures, there is really no need to use `exec` at all. In fact, the only thing you are really doing is creating methods so that `self.func_...` will bind the method for you, since you need a function with the signature of your slot and access to `self`. You can write a simple method that will generate functions that you can assign to your slots directly. The advantage of doing it this way is that (a) you avoid calling `exec` entirely, and (b) you don't need to have a bunch of similarly named auto-generated methods polluting your class namespace. The slot generator would look something like this:

```
def create_slots_i(self, c):
    def slot_func():
        self.do_something(c)  # This is a real closure now
    slot_func.__name__ = f'func_{c}'
    return slot_func
```

Since you will not be referring to these function objects anywhere except your slots, `__name__` is the only way to get the "name" under which they were stored. That is the same thing that `def` does for you under the hood.

You can now assign slots directly:

```
some_widget.some_signal.connect(self.create_slots_i('a'))
```

**Note**

I originally had a more complex approach in mind for you, since I thought you cared about generating bound methods, instead of just setting `__name__`. In case you have a sufficiently complex scenario where it still applies, here is my original blurb:

A quick recap of the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html): when you bind a function with the dot operator, e.g., `t.func_a`, python looks at the class for descriptors with that name. If your class has a data descriptor (like `property`, but not functions), then that descriptor will shadow anything you may have placed in the instance `__dict__`. However, if you have a non-data descriptor (one a `__get__` method but without a `__set__` method, like a function object), then it will only be bound if an instance attribute does not shadow it. Once this decision has been made, actually invoking the descriptor protocol involves calling `type(t).func_a.__get__(t)`. That's how a bound method knows about `self`.

Now you can return a bound method from within your generator:

```
def create_slots_i(self, c):
    def slot_func(self):
        self.do_something(c)  # This is a closure on `c`, but not on `self` until you bind it
    slot_func.__name__ = f'func_{c}'
    return slot_func.__get__(self)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The use of `__name__` is really inspiring! However, in the example in the session "Internal Closures', you are still using "Copy `globals`". You can refer to my answer, which avoid copying of `globals` at all.

Comment: It is hard for me to decide which answer to accept. Since you solve my "Original Problem"  perfectly, and I think my answer works fine on the problem described in "Edited2".  Would you mind editing your answer and adding a reference link to my answer? To be straight, I think my answer provide a better explaination on the "Internal Closures" method. Perhaps providing a link to my answer can help the reader get a better comprehesion. I will be glad to accept your answer if you can correct the example in the session "Internal Closures' and add a reference link to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Why this phenomena happen:**

Actually [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749806/9758790) of the [question 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2749655/9758790) listed above can answer this question.

When call `exec()` on one code string, the code string is first compiled. I suppose that during compiling, the provided `globals` and `locals` is not considered. The symbol in the  exec()ed code str is compiled to be in the globals. So the function defined in the code str will be considered using global variables, and thus  `__closure__` is set to `None`.

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29456463/9758790) for more information about what the func `exec` does.

---

**How to deal with this phenomena:**

*Imitating the solutions provided in the previous questions*, for the minimal demostration the question, it can also be modified this way to work:

```
a=1  # moving out of the variable 'code'
code = """\
def f1():
    print(a)
print(f1.__closure__)
f1()
"""

def foo():
    exec(code)

foo()
```

Although the `__closure__` is still `None`, the exception can be avoided because now only the global symbol is needed and `__closure__` should also be None if correctly set. You can read the part *The reason why the solutions work* in the question body for more information.

---

*This was originally added in [Revision 4](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72335222/4) of the question.*

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

To set correct `__closure__` attribute of function defined in the code string passed to `exec()` function. Just wrap the total code string with a function definition.

I provide an example here to demonstrate all possible situations. Suppose you want to define a function named `foo` inside a code string used by `exec()`. The foo use function, variables that defined inside and outside the code string:

```
def f1():
    outside_local_variable = "this is local variable defined outside code str"
    def outside_local_function():
        print("this is function defined outside code str")
    code = """\
local_variable = "this is local variable defined inside code str"
def local_function():
    print("this is function defined inside code str")
def foo():
    print(local_variable)
    local_function()
    print(outside_local_variable)
    outside_local_function()
foo()
"""
    exec(code)

f1()
```

It can be wrapper like this:

```
def f1():
    outside_local_variable = "this is local variable defined outside code str"
    def outside_local_function():
        print("this is function defined outside code str")
    code = """\
def closure_helper_func(outside_local_variable, outside_local_function):
    local_variable = "this is local variable defined inside code str"
    def local_function():
        print("this is function defined inside code str")
    def foo():
        print(local_variable)
        local_function()
        print(outside_local_variable)
        outside_local_function()
    foo()
closure_helper_func(outside_local_variable, outside_local_function)
"""
    exec(code)

f1()
```

---

### Detailed explanation:

**Why the `__closure__` attribute is not corretly set:**

please refer to The [community wiki answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72340516/9758790).

**How to set the `__closure__` attribute to what's expected:**

Just wrap the whole code str with a helper function definition and call the helper function once, then during compiling, the variables are considered to be local, and will be stored in the `__closure__` attribute.

For the minimal demonstration in the question, it can be modified to following:

```
code = """\
def closure_helper_func():
    a=1
    def f1():
        print(a)
    print(f1.__closure__)
    f1()
closure_helper_func()
"""

def foo():
    exec(code)

foo()
```

This output as expected

```
(<cell at 0x0000019CE6239A98: int object at 0x00007FFF42BFA1A0>,)
1
```

The example above provide a way to add symbols that defined in the code str to the `__closure__` For example, in the minimal demo, a=1 is a defined inside the code str. But **what if one want to add the local symbols defined outside the code str**? For example, in the code snippet in EDIT1 session, the `self` symbol needs to be added to the `__closure__`, and the symbol is provided in the locals() when `exec()` is called. **Just add the name of these symbols to the arguments of helper function** and you can handle this situation.

---

The following shows how to fix the problem in EDIT1 session.

```
class test_wrapper_function():
    def __init__(self):
        define_function_str = '''\
def closure_helper_func(self):
    def temp_func():
        return self.func()
    self.wrappered_func2 = temp_func
closure_helper_func(self)
'''
        exec(define_function_str)

    def func(self):
        print("hi!")

t = test_wrapper_function()
t.wrappered_func2()
```

---

The following shows how to fix the codes in the session "Why I want to do this"

```
class MyWidget():
    def __init__(self):
        self.create_slots_family()

    def do_something(self, character):
        # in fact, this function is much more complex. Do some simplification.
        print(character)

    def create_slots_i(self, character):
        # want to define a function like this:
        # if character is 'C', define self.func_C such that self.func_C() works like self.do_something(C)
        # create_slot_command_str = "self.func_" + character + " = lambda:self.do_something('" + character + "')"
        create_slot_command_str = """
def closure_helper_func(self):
    self.func_""" + character + " = lambda:self.do_something('" + character + """')
closure_helper_func(self)
"""
        # print(create_slot_command_str)
        exec(create_slot_command_str)

    def create_slots_family(self):
        for c in ["A", "B", "C", "D"]:
            self.create_slots_i(c)

my_widget = MyWidget()
my_widget.func_A()
```

---

This solution seems to be too tricky. However, I can not find a more elegant way to declare that some variables should be local symbol during compiling.

Comment: I just noticed that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/872082/9758790) have already proposed this kind of solution, which I ignored before.